# what effect if the world have a single massive world giant tree?

Tags: biology, physics, science-in-society, geophysics

you know stuff like ygdrasil tree but just a normal tree but the biggest and tallest in the world, i wonder what the effect to the world ? for an example if the root grow to surpass the continental and oceanic plate either it only cover some parts or entire world, can it stop earthquake or make it even worst to the zone covered by the root?

Comment: Answering this question would require enough books to cover a master degree. Narrow it down, please.

Comment: what part i should remove ?
is this ok ?

Comment: Narrowing it down isn't about _removing_. The number of different effects of having a single giant tree is _enormous_. Concentrate on just one aspect, and ask about that to start with.

Comment: how about this ? is this fine ?

Comment: You may want to put your question into the [Sandbox for proposed questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), where you can work on it to make it a good fit for this site. If you got a good question by then, feel free to post it here again.